# Does rails' multi-level delegation violates demeter law?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, delegates

Rails allows us to delegate methods to other objects by using simple macro-like syntax. However, I'm in confusion on a particular case.

If I delegate a method to obtain an object and then delegate another method to that new object, will it break the demeter law?

For example, in a `Course` class

```
#course.rb
...
belongs_to :batch
...
```

and it an `Exam` class

```
#exam.rb
...
belongs_to :course

delegate :batch, to: :course
...
# access some batch's method like this

batch.name # which really is course.batch.name
```

Is it a violation? What could be the possible solution?

Comment: That's how you are supposed to do it.

Comment: @dan-klasson Thank you to have the time to answer this. So, Demeter law is really telling me just not to access 3rd object's method directly in a method chain? not not to access at all?

Comment: Exactly. So if it changes in the future you don't have to refactor it everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would argue that delegation (even multiple levels deep) does not violate the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), because you do not actually call the method on the unit two levels away.

Delegation improves loose coupled components, because you can replace a delegation in a unit with a method and change its implementation, without other units need to change.

The law tells you not to depend on the internal of an external object. It is okay to access its values, but through a proper interface. That interface might be - in its most simple form - a delegator.

Comment: I got the point clearly now. The job of delegation is to simply remove the burden of changing every method call, when a change is necessary. btw, You may want to revise this portion `change is implementation`, i think, it is `'its`